# select statement that selects distinct based on rownumber

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a very simple query, but some booking columns repeat and if they do i do not want to show them, however the entire row is not the same how can i make it so if the row is a duplicate show the one with the max total.

```
SELECT     PREMIUMYEAR, 
           LASTNAME, 
           FIRSTNAME, 
           BOOKING, 
           CLAIMTYPE, 
           DEPARTUREDATE, 
           [PLAN], 
           INCIDENT, 
           RESERVEAMOUNT, 
           FINALSTATUS, 
           AGE, 
           TOTAL
FROM       dbo.[table]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you are getting and what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT PREMIUMYEAR, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, BOOKING, CLAIMTYPE, DEPARTUREDATE, [PLAN], INCIDENT, RESERVEAMOUNT, FINALSTATUS, AGE, TOTAL
    FROM (SELECT PREMIUMYEAR, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, BOOKING, CLAIMTYPE, DEPARTUREDATE, [PLAN], INCIDENT, RESERVEAMOUNT, FINALSTATUS, AGE, TOTAL,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BOOKING ORDER BY TOTAL DESC) AS RowNum
              FROM dbo.[table]) t
    WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: thanks that worked great, but i actually realized i should be sum the other totals not just ignoring them could i just do sum(total) as total in the second select and remove the order by total?